# Run the robotframework remote library keyword with TypeError: run_keyword() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: robotframework

Run the robotframework remote library keyword with TypeError

remote.py code

```
from robotremoteserver import RobotRemoteServer
from WiseLibrary import WiseLibrary

RobotRemoteServer(WiseLibrary(),host="0.0.0.0")
```

test.robot code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Remote    http://127.0.0.1:8270/
Suite Teardown    Delete Wise Sessions

*** Test Cases ***
test01
    ${name}    Generate App Name    5
    ${resp}    Create Application    name=${name}
    Verify Code And Data    ${resp}    201    name=${name}
    [Teardown]    Delete Application Teardown    ${name}
```

It looks like Connection got established to the library because I can see the reflection of keywords in RIDE

```
python -m robot.libdoc Remote::http://127.0.0.1:38270 list
Create Application
Delete Application Teardown
Delete Wise Sessions
Verify Code And Data 
Generate App Name
......
```

But while executing any keyword I am getting following error:

> FAIL : TypeError: run_keyword() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)